# Tamil translate in android

Tags: android, api, translate, tamil

How do I translate/convert Thanglish to tamil script on android?
I googled a lot but didn't find any hints, could someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: give me some more details. actually i need app with thanglish to tamil translation in space click how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are online tools like quillpad and tamiltyping and apps in android like Tanglish to do that. If you want to develop one in android, you can translate as the vowels and consonants are typed in english, and add a tamil dictionary to make sure the spelling is right.

Comment: I have unicode values for vowels and consonants how do integrate with android  code

Answer (score 1):

you have to use google translate API if you want to translate texts dynamically. Refer this link.
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs?csw=1